# Looking for a more elegant way to check to see if a nullable property changed

Tags: vb.net

If I had many properties of type SqlDate or perhaps Date?, this way of checking to see if the property changed can be monotonous.

How would you implement this check? Perhaps as an extension method on the SqlDate type? Or is there a more common way?

```
Public Property StayDate() As SqlDateTime
    Get
        Return _StayDate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As SqlDateTime)
        If (value.IsNull And Not _StayDate.IsNull) OrElse
           (Not value.IsNull And _StayDate.IsNull) OrElse
           (value <> _StayDate) Then
            _Changed = True
        End If
        _StayDate = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Converted C# :

```
public SqlDateTime StayDate {
    get { return _StayDate; }
    set {
        if ((value.IsNull   & !_StayDate.IsNull) || 
                 (!value.IsNull & _StayDate.IsNull)  || 
                 (value != _StayDate)) 
        {
            _Changed = true;
        }
        _StayDate = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not simply using _Changed = value != _StayDate?  SqlDateTime implements all the comparison operators.

Comment: In SQL, comparing any value to null yields NULL. It looks like the C# objects do the same. I just retested it.

Comment: Where is the date being changed: your database or your application? If it is your application, inherit from SQLDateTime, and extend it with an event that gets raised when there is an actual value change. It should be very easy to swap out the type of your new SQLDateTime for the included one.